# can I use flexbox and float at the same time? or use flexbox with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-float

for example if I have a 2 column layout (main content and a aside) Can I float the main to the left and aside to left/right and then use flexbox to give the aside an equal height compared to the main content?

Do I have to display the whole container to flexbox to include header,main content, aside, and footer or can I just cherry pick one area to use flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

From [Overview](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#overview),

> Flex layout is superficially similar to block layout. It lacks many of
>   the more complex text- or document-centric properties that can be used
>   in block layout, such as [floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats)

From [Flex Containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers),

> [`float`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-float) and [`clear`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) have no effect on a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), and do
>   not take it out-of-flow. However, the [`float`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-float) property can still
>   affect box generation by influencing the [`display`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display) property’s
>   computed value.

From [Absolutely-Positioned Flex Children](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#abspos-items),

> An absolutely-positioned child of a [flex container](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-container) does not
>   participate in flex layout. However, it does participate in the
>   [reordering step](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#algo-flex-order) (see [`order`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#propdef-order)), which has an effect in their
>   painting order.