# Aligning elements inside a box

Tags: css, css-float, flexbox

I am trying to align items inside a div, I've read some questions but still have this doubt.

What I currently have:

[image: What it looks like]

The code is

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.image {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.title {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  float: right; /* Does not work */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="image">
    <img src="http://opae.a-superlab.com/forum/styles/art_air/imageset/forum_read.png">
  </span>
  <span class="title">Category Title</span>
  <p>Category description</p>
</div>
```

The `float: right` for category description is NOT working :( I want it to be positioned in extreme right side of the block.

Setting `margin-left` to an explicit length is not an option because the content of "category description" is variable.

Comment: The question seems a mix of [Right-aligning flex item?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429003/right-aligning-flex-item) and [Can I use flexbox and float at the same time?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31953105/1529630).

Comment: <div
  style="border: 1px solid black; width: 50%; display: flex; align-items: center;">
  <span style="border: 1px solid green;"> <img
   src="http://opae.a-superlab.com/forum/styles/art_air/imageset/forum_read.png"></span>
  <div style="float: left; width: 100%; ">
  <span style="border: 1px solid blue; margin-left: 1%;">Category
   Title</span>
  <p style="border: 1px solid red; float: right">Category
   description</p>
 </div>
 </div>

Comment: it is working... just add margins to adjust it.

Comment: @Oriol please don't be so hasty and allow me to rephrase the question :|
I want a solution to this problem

edit-- nevermind, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using flexbox, so `float` is ignored as explained in the spec:

- In [Overview](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#overview):

  > Flex layout is superficially similar to block layout. It lacks many of
  >   the more complex text- or document-centric properties that can be used
  >   in block layout, such as [floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats) and [columns](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-multicol/).
- In [Flex Containers](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-containers)

  > [`float`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-float) and [`clear`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-clear) have no effect on a [flex item](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-item), and
  >   do not take it out-of-flow. However, the [`float`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-float) property can
  >   still affect box generation by influencing the [`display`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css2/visuren.html#propdef-display)
  >   property’s computed value.
- In an example in [Flex Items](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-items)

  ```html
  <div style="display:flex">
      <!-- flex item: floated element; floating is ignored -->
      <div id="item2" style="float: left;">float</div>
  </div>
  ```

However, as explained in [Right-aligning flex item?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22429003/1529630), in flexbox you can use `margin-left: auto` to push a flex item to the right:

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.image {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.title {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin-left: 1%;
}
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <span class="image">
    <img src="http://opae.a-superlab.com/forum/styles/art_air/imageset/forum_read.png">
  </span>
  <span class="title">Category Title</span>
  <p>Category description</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Okay so how do I achieve what I want without using flexbox? I want it to look exactly like the current output of code except for category description to move to extreme right.

Comment: As explained in [Right-aligning flex item?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22429003/1529630), in flexbox you can use `margin-left: auto` to push a flex item to the right.

Comment: thanks a lot! That helped me and sorry for asking a question that was already answered!